# React Apexcharts not resizing when drawer opens

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I am using MUI mini variant drawer, I have set the main div content where the outlet is at to be padded by 100px when the drawer is closed partially and 300px when the drawer is opened, it's working fine on all components except react apexcharts they don't get resized until I refresh the page, I have tried the following
1 - Changing the chart options when the drawer is toggled in order for it to re-render
but yet I am still facing the same issue

```
export const ChartComponent = ({options, series, type}) => {
    return (
        <Chart options={options} series={series} width='100%'  height='300'
               type={type}/>
    )
}
```

That's my chart component

````
 const [stockSummary, setStockSummary] = useState({

        series: [{
            name: '',
            type: 'column',
            data: [75, 85, 72, 100, 50, 100, 80, 75, 95, 35, 75, 100]
        }, {
            name: '',
            type: 'area',
            data: [44, 65, 55, 75, 45, 55, 40, 60, 75, 45, 50, 42]
        }, {
            name: '',
            type: 'line',
            data: [30, 25, 45, 30, 25, 35, 20, 45, 35, 20, 35, 20]
        }],
        options: {
            chart: {
                height: 300,
                type: 'line',
                stacked: false,
                toolbar: {
                    show: false,
                },
            },
            stroke: {
                width: [0, 1, 1],
                curve: 'straight',
                dashArray: [0, 0, 5]
            },
            legend: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'poppins',
                labels: {
                    colors: '#888888',
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    columnWidth: '18%',
                    borderRadius: 6,

                }
            },

            fill: {
                type: 'gradient',
                gradient: {
                    inverseColors: false,
                    shade: 'light',
                    type: "vertical",

                    colorStops: [
                        [
                            {
                                offset: 0,
                                color: '#1C2E9E',
                                opacity: 1
                            },
                            {
                                offset: 100,
                                color: '#1C2E9E',
                                opacity: 1
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                offset: 0,
                                color: '#3AC977',
                                opacity: 1
                            },
                            {
                                offset: 0.4,
                                color: '#3AC977',
                                opacity: .15
                            },
                            {
                                offset: 100,
                                color: '#3AC977',
                                opacity: 0
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                offset: 0,
                                color: '#FF5E5E',
                                opacity: 1
                            },
                            {
                                offset: 100,
                                color: '#FF5E5E',
                                opacity: 1
                            }
                        ],
                    ],
                    stops: [0, 100, 100, 100]
                }
            },
            colors: ["#1C2E9E", "#3AC977", "#FF5E5E"],
            labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
            ],
            markers: {
                size: 0
            },
            xaxis: {
                type: 'month',
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        colors: '#888888',
                    },
                },
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                opposite: true,
                tickAmount: 4,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        colors: '#888888',
                    },
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                intersect: false,
                y: {
                    formatter: function (y) {
                        if (typeof y !== "undefined") {
                            return y.toFixed(0) + " points";
                        }
                        return y;

                    }
                }
            },
        }


    })
    const [barChart, setBarChart] = useState({
        series: [
            {
                name: '',
                data: [31, 40, 28, 31, 40, 28, 31, 40, 28, 31, 40, 28]
            },


        ],
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                height: 300,


                toolbar: {
                    show: false,
                },

            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: false,
                    endingShape: 'rounded',
                    columnWidth: '45%',
                    borderRadius: 5,

                },
            },
            colors: ['#', '#77248B'],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            markers: {
                shape: "circle",
            },
            legend: {
                show: false,
                fontSize: '12px',
                labels: {
                    colors: '#000000',

                },
                markers: {
                    width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    strokeWidth: 0,
                    strokeColor: '#fff',
                    fillColors: undefined,
                    radius: 35,
                }
            },
            stroke: {
                show: true,
                width: 6,
                colors: ['transparent']
            },
            grid: {
                borderColor: 'rgba(252, 252, 252,0.2)',
            },
            xaxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Agu', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nev', 'Dec'],
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        colors: '#000',
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                        fontWeight: 100,
                        cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
                    },
                },
                axisBorder: {
                    show: false,
                },
                axisTicks: {
                    show: false,
                    borderType: 'solid',
                    color: '#78909C',
                    height: 6,
                    offsetX: 0,
                    offsetY: 0
                },
                crosshairs: {
                    show: false,
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                labels: {
                    offsetX: -16,
                    style: {
                        colors: '#000',
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                        fontWeight: 100,
                        cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
                    },
                },
            },
            fill: {
                opacity: 1,
                colors: ['#1C2E9E', '#FFD125'],
            },
            tooltip: {
                y: {
                    formatter: function (val) {
                        return val
                    }
                }
            },
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 575,
                options: {
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            columnWidth: '1%',
                            borderRadius: -1,
                        },
                    },
                    chart: {
                        height: 250,
                    },
                    series: [
                        {
                            name: 'Projects',
                            data: [31, 40, 28, 31, 40, 28, 31, 40]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Projects',
                            data: [11, 32, 45, 31, 40, 28, 31, 40]
                        },

                    ],
                }
            }]
        }
    })
    ```
    and those are the options
````